# HTML "Input" button stops working when inserted in a <div> tag

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu

I'm trying to make my site mobile friendly by creating a collapsible menu when a device that is 480px or smaller is used. I found a great demo and it works perfectly: [How To Create A Responsive Navigation Menu Using Only CSS](http://medialoot.com/blog/how-to-create-a-responsive-navigation-menu-using-only-css/)
I want to customize the menu and put it in a Header div tag. You can go to the link above to see the full code for this. It DOES work, however, if I insert the HTML code into a div tag, it stops working! I can put the entire amount of code into a div tag, but that defeats the purpose of using straight HTML and CSS ONLY to create this collapsible menu!

I want to set this up as a two-column website when it is viewed on a laptop or PC with the menu on the left. I have that working just fine, but as soon as I change the menu to use the collapsible menu inside the header div, it stops working!

So my code is as follows:

```
<div id="header">
<div class="topcenter">
    <p>Consultants and Suppliers of <br />Affordable, Natural, Quality,
    <br />Sustainable Power Solutions!</p>
</div>
<label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<div id="left">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#" title="Power" >Power Up Belize</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS is almost exactly the same as in the example - I've proven that it works when the label and input box are NOT inside the header div tag, but it ALSO breaks as soon as I put the menu HTML inside the wrapper div! What gives? How come I can't get the input box to work correctly inside a div tag?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Here is my updated code (and it still doesn't work :-( )

```
    @media screen and (max-width : 480px)
{
    /*Change Header imge and font size for Mobile */
    #header
    {
        position: relative;
        top: .25em;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 90%;
        font-weight: Bold;
        padding-bottom: 2.5em;
        background-image: url('../images/PUBLogoSm.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center top;
        width: 100%;
        height: 130px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .topcenter
    {
        position: relative;
        top: 6em;
        text-align: center;
        color: #017f02;
        width: 99%;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-bottom:1em;
    }

    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
        }
    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
        }
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
        }
    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    #show-menu, #menu {
        display: none;
        }
    #show-menu:checked ~ #menu {
        display: block;
    }
}


    <div id="header">
    <div class="topcenter">
        <p>Consultants and Suppliers of <br />
         Affordable, Natural, Quality,<br />Sustainable Power Solutions!</p>
    </div>
    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="left">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="#" title="Power" >Power Up Belize</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Experience</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move `<input type="checkbox" ...` right before `<ul id="menu">`. That way, the general sibling selector `~` or next sibling selector `+` will start to work again.

```css
#show-menu, #menu {
    display: none;
}
#show-menu:checked ~ #menu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button"/>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Power Up Belize</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Edit:** **[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/L6mw5b0q/)** with media query implemented.